# developing an app that integrates with bitcoin

Tags: coinbase.com, php

is there something like the paypal sandbox test accounts for coinbase that I could use to test the app that I'm developing?

Comment: i think btcipn.com have tesnet IPN, my friends told me once but didn't check yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are integrating with bitcoin directly, then you can use the bitcoin testnet (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet).

If you are using a payment processor, Coinbase does not have sandbox feature like PayPal, although they have expressed interest in creating one based on bitcoin's testnet.  Coinbase does allow sending test payment notifications (IPN) from their merchant settings page (https://coinbase.com/merchant_settings).

Bitpay's FAQ (https://bitpay.com/faq) states that they too do not have a sandbox, and advises testing with small amounts of BTC.

Comment: BitPay do support testnet now. https://test.bitpay.com/

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat yes. Bitcoin has a [Testnet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet) that is a fully functioning Bitcoin network (you can even mine on it) but isn't really traded for money. It's safe to use and send transactions to.

Comment: Apologies - I missed the bit about Coinbase specifically. You're really integrating with Coinbase in that case, not 'Bitcoin'. If you wanted to interact with a test Bitcoin network itself, then my answer is valid.